# mySQL remove all text from record except keyword

Tags: mysql

I'm basically looking to remove all of the text from a record called `FaxOutNumber` except for where it contains `no`... it isn't consistent in the records, so sometimes its just `NO!` and other times its `no@emailaddress.com`.

I'd like:

```
FaxOutNumber:
5145555@emailaddress.com
no!@emailadrress.com
```

to change to:

```
FaxOutNumber:
[null]
no
```

I'd actually like to just turn this field into a simple BIT where the "No" becomes a "1" or true value as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN isNoRecord BOOLEAN;
UPDATE my_table SET isNoRecord = FaxOutNumber RLIKE '^no(!?)(@.+)?$';
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN FaxOutNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this--

```
UPDATE tableName SET FaxOutNumber = IF(FaxOutNumber RLIKE '^par',"",FaxOutNumber);
```